# Nofication.Builder doesn't work

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

When I hover over the object this massage displayed:

> required android.app.nofication found android.app.notification.Builder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this);
```

Generally, the whole code is something like this:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("Title");
notificationBuilder.setContentText("Text");
notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.your_icon);
notificationBuilder.setTicker("Ticker");
notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

nm.notify(notificationID, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score -1):

You have forgot the `.build();`

Like this:

```
Notification noti=new Notification.Builder(MainActivity.this).build();
```